# how to transfer codeigniter site from localhost to live server

Tags: codeigniter

I developed a site in codeigniter with basic functionality now i want to update this site to my live server. But when i uploaded my site to live server it shows 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND.

http://www.nawtist.com/test/ams/

Please tell me what do i need to do. I searched a lot about this but i didn't found any helpful information. So is there any base_url or anything else that i need to change before upload this on live server really appreciate

Comment: What version of codeigniter? What does your config.php look like? Are you using an htaccess file? If so, what's in it? Where is the installation on your server? What have you tried so far to debug the problem? Please [edit] your post and include this information. And by the way your site does work when you add `index.php`: http://www.nawtist.com/test/ams/index.php/user/login

Comment: change the config url to match your domain, also if your class's are capitalized change them to lower case, I have run into that problem.  Also make sure you have a controllers dir(its needed, even if empty)

Answer (score 1):

And remember, many servers are case-sensitive and with CodeIgniter v3 you should change the controller's first letter file and model's first letter file to upper case. That worked for me too.
Best

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your htaccess file or mod_rewrite is disable on that server. 
When you go to [page with index.php](http://www.nawtist.com/index.php/test/ams/) it works (although css file doesn't work because of bad routing)

also check if `$config['index_page']='';` if it should work without index.php

Comment: Thanks Problem was in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem times ago and there are 4 points in codeigniter to care about as I remember:

- Check **base_url** value in your "config.php"
- Check **database** settings in "database.php"
- Check **.htaccess** file contents if you have defined it once
- Check **routes.php** if you have defined any custom routes

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing **404 page not found** in Codeigniter after upload file local to live server then follow these steps

1. change your controller and file name first letter capital
2. same change as above in model class and file name i.e first letter capital

After following steps above your problem can be solve Thank you.